# Drupal 6: How do I only call up "events" by upcoming date?

Tags: events, drupal, date, drupal-6, view

I am a newbie to Drupal so this may be a simple answer...

I am building a site that on the homepage I want to be able to call up events that will happen in the next 6 months and then disappear after the event has past. I have made a field called event_start_date that you can enter the "From" and "To" dates. I already used Views to call up the event and I have it placed on the homepage. I just need the correct values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a 'Filter' on the Date:date(node). In the first configuration screen that opens, you just need to select your date field. In the second, toggle the operator to "Is Between".

Go to the Relative Value section, and for *Date Default* enter `now`. For *To Date Default* enter `now +176 days`.